# How do I automatically launch Azure Function in a local environment?

Tags: java, azure, maven, rest-assured

I have two Azure functions linked together. I want to test them locally using Rest Assured. But to do this, I have to manually run them every time before the tests. Is there any way to automate this moment? So that when the test starts, the service starts automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to include a step to start your application (function app) using Azure Functions Core CLI. If you do not have that already you have to set it up: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=v4%2Cwindows%2Ccsharp%2Cportal%2Cbash%2Ckeda.

To start your application with command line you can use `func host start`. Posting a documentation for reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=v4%2Cwindows%2Ccsharp%2Cportal%2Cbash%2Ckeda#start.